# Add rows to a password protected excel sheet, without the password

Tags: microsoft-excel

I need a excel sheet that behaves exactly like a password protected sheet(not editable, not deletable etc), except that it allows adding new rows without the password.

Is there any way to achieve this?

I am willing to write macros if needed.

 Basically what I am trying to achieve is, , the future users of the excel sheet will be able to add new rows, but wont be able edit them once added.

 Now when I think about it, another way to achieve this would be to somehow have two different passwords for the same excel - one that allows only adding to empty cells, the other that allows everything. Is that possible?

Comment: What you want can be done using a VBA macro. You would need to have a button that the user presses, the button would unlock the worksheet, add a row and lock it again.

You would need to be careful and password protect the VBA section itself, otherwise a clever user could edit the macro to find out what the password is.

Comment: this sounds to be a good solution. Have never written VBA macros, so might need some more help from this community with that :)

Comment: SuperUser is not a "please write me a script" kind of service though. But what you need is to press the record macro button in excel, do the actions manually and stop the record. Now you have the VBA code. You just need to put it on a button.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft tells you [a procedure](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/214081/xl-how-to-lock-individual-cells-in-a-worksheet) to lock parts of a WorkSheet like:

**If You Want the Majority of Cells Locked**

To lock the majority of the cells on the worksheet, follow these steps:

1. Select List item the cells that you want to remain unprotected. To
   select nonadjacent (noncontiguous) cells, hold down CTRL and click
   the cells that are to remain unprotected.
2. On Excel show the format cells dialog box by clicking the Expand
   button to the bottom right of the Font section of the Home ribbon,
   and then click Protection tab.
3. Click to clear the Locked check box and click OK.
4. In Excel click the Review tab, and click Protect Sheet. Type a
   password if you want one, and then click OK.

**If You Want the Majority of Cells Unlocked**

To leave the majority of the cells on the worksheet unlocked, follow these steps:

1. Select the entire worksheet by clicking the Select All button (the
   gray rectangle in the upper-left corner of the worksheet where the
   row 1 and column A headings meet), or by pressing CTRL+A or
   CTRL+SHIFT+SPACEBAR.
2. Excel show the format cells dialog box by clicking the Expand button
   to the bottom right of the Font section of the Home ribbon, and then
   click Protection tab.
3. Click to clear the Locked check box and click OK. Select the cells
   that you want to protect. To select nonadjacent (noncontiguous)
   cells, hold down CTRL and click the cells that you want to protect.
4. Return to the Format Cells dialog box, and then click the Protection
   tab. Click to select the Locked check box, and then click OK.
5. In Excel click the Review tab, and click Protect Sheet. Type a
   password, if you want one, and then click OK.

Comment: If I do this, the cells I selected to be unprotected will remain unprotected forever right.  What I am trying to achieve is, the future users of the excel sheet will be able to add new rows, but wont be able edit them once added

Comment: You'd have to keep protecting new cells in a periodic basis. What you want is a Write-Only Spread Sheet, and that is not something Excel does.